# How do I find out where emacs 24 (OSX) puts my aspell corrections?

Tags: macos, emacs, aspell

I would like to see if it's possible to back them up into github with the rest of my dotfiles.

I searched the [config options](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/aspell.htm), but am only seeing the default dictionaries used. I'd like to know where my custom word spelling corrections are being saved at.

I've found that by [evaluating `ispell-personal-dictionary`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Spelling.html), I see `nil`. This means

> the spelling program looks for a personal dictionary in a default location.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in your home directory, specifically, `.aspell.en.prel`, and `.aspell.en.pws`.